# Managing HttpClient in a F# WebAssembly app

Tags: f#, dotnet-httpclient, bolero

What is the best practice is to "register" the http client in one place, so it can be reused from this Elmish update function? Instead of having to create it for every request.

```
let update message model =
    match message with
    | SetMessage s -> { model with x = s }
    | Loading -> { model with x = "Doing something long ..." }

let handleClick model dispatch _ = 
    dispatch Loading
    async {
        let url = Uri "https://api.github.com"
        -- FIXME: too expensive to do this on per-update basis
        use httpClient = new HttpClient(BaseAddress = url)
        let! resp = httpClient.GetAsync "/users/srid" |> Async.AwaitTask
        let! s = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        dispatch (SetMessage s)
    } |> Async.Start
```

I feel like this would normally go in Startup.fs. I use a client-only Bolero web app, so this would look like:

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(new HttpClient (BaseAddress=apiBase))
```

But then the question becomes ... how do I access it from my program in F#? What is the idiomatic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would either be to add HttpClient as another field in your model or as another parameter to your update function.

```
let update (client:HttpClient) message model = // Your code

let url = Uri "https://api.github.com"
let httpClient = new HttpClient(BaseAddress = url)
```

In general you shouldn't "do work" in your view and, by extension, event handlers. Instead, you should use the Elmish [Cmd module](https://elmish.github.io/elmish/cmd.html) something like this:

```
let update httpClient message model =
    match message with
    | SetMessage s -> 
        { model with x = s }, Cmd.none
    | GetMessageAsync -> 
        let cmd = 
            let getHttp () = 
                async {
                    let! resp = httpClient.GetAsync "/users/srid" |> Async.AwaitTask
                    return! resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                }
            Cmd.OfAsync.perform getHttp () (fun s -> SetMessage s)

        { model with x = "Doing something long ..." }, cmd

let handleClick model dispatch _ = 
    dispatch GetMessageAsync
```

Comment: Yea, that makes sense - re: `Cmd`. I have chosen `Cmd.OfAsync.either` instead, as that handles exceptions. Also, I put the HttpClient in `Startup.fs` as a registerd service. https://github.com/srid/fsharp-wasm-static-demo